# How to create multiple git repositories in one sourceforge project

Tags: git, shell, sourceforge

Source forge explains that first I have to create a shell service (https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/Shell%20Service/). For example in git bash:

```
ssh -t USER@shell.sourceforge.net create
```

with USER my user name. It works perfectly well.

Then sourceforge explains how to access the repo (https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/Git/?version=4). First I have to navigate to the git repo with:

```
cd /home/scm_git/P/PR/PROJECTUNIXNAME
```

with:

- PROJECTUNIXNAME the UNIX name of the project
- P the  first letter of that name,
- and PR the first two letters of the name

I am trying that with my protoframework project, with:

```
cd /home/scm_git/p/pr/protoframework
```

But i have the following error in the bash:

```
bash: cd: /home/scm_git/p/pr/protoframework: No such file or directory
```

What did I do wrong?

I also tried without the `pr` with:

```
cd /home/scm_git/p/protoframework
```

But had the same error.

If I try the same kind of command but for other content (for example project-web), it works fine.

Comment: Try `sf-help --scm` and `cd /home/git/p/protoframework`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the correct path:

```
cd /home/scm_git/p/protoframework/CODE.git
```

with `CODE` the name chosen for the git repo when creating the project. So by default this will be:

```
cd /home/scm_git/p/protoframework/code.git
```

After that step, the sourceforge wiki is correct. For example to create a repo called `myrepo`:

```
git --git-dir=myrepo init --shared=all --bare
```